# How can I optimize the story tags of my Kindle Vella story?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, tools, marketing

How do I know what are the best story tag words/phrases to use?

I want to "drive" potential readers to my Kindle Vella story.  Kindle Vella's web says very little about this.

If feels like Amazon's attitude is:  "Here's our great, new tool to easily publish your serial episodes.  You want people to read it?  We've got a great app for that.
What?  You want people to find your story?  Just enter 7 story tags.
What story tags should you use?   You're on your own, buster."

Answer (score 1):

1. What is your story about? Make a list of tropes and motifs.
2. Go to Kindle Vella and look for stories that are in the same genre, for the same audience, and contain similar tropes and motifs. Make a list of the tags of those stories.
3. Understand your target audience. What will they be searching for? What terms will they use to find this?
4. Where do all these researches overlap? What is the intersection of the three sets of words and phrases?
5. Within the intersection, which are the seven tags that describe the most important aspects of your story?
6. There you are.

Comment: Thanks. Is this an idea that you have, or do you use these 6 steps to get readers for your specific Vella story?  If so, what story?